# Wildfly 14 domain - Connection timeout

Tags: jboss, virtualbox, wildfly

**Situation:** Windows 10 Host machine needs to communicate with Fedora 26 virtual machine. Windows 10 is my host in domain, fedora is slave. VirtualBox machine has 2 adapters, one is Bridged, and the other is Internal Network Adapter.

IPv4 of my host machine is: 192.168.0.17
Slave machine IP is: 192.168.0.35

When running domain on Windows, and accessing 192.168.0.17:9990 I can bring up management console. But when starting domain on Fedora, it says Connection timeout, cant connect to remote://192.168.0.17:9990
Picture below is my current situation.

**What have I done:** I have disabled and stopped firewalld on fedora, iptables aren't running, as I can't even disable them.

I have enabled firewall rule on windows that lets me communicate between host and vm.

I have tried pinging Host machine from Fedora, and it is all good.
I have tried changing ports on `<static-discovery/>` tag, but it won't ping 9990, nor 9999.

I have tried connecting to host management console via jboss-cli on host machine, and it is working.

I have tried connecting to host management console via jboss-cli on slave machine, and it is working.

My host.xml file on Windows:

```
<management-interfaces>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <http-upgrade enabled="true"/>
            <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
<domain-controller>
    <local/>
</domain-controller>
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.0.17}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.0.17}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecured">
        <inet-address value="192.168.0.17"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

My host.xml file on slave:

```
<domain-controller>
<remote security-realm="ManagementRealm">
  <discovery-options>
    <static-discovery name="master-native" protocol="remote"  host="192.168.0.17" port="9999" />
    <static-discovery name="master-https" protocol="https-remoting" host="192.168.0.17" port="9993" security-realm="ManagementRealm"/>
    <static-discovery name="master-http" protocol="http-remoting" host="192.168.0.17" port="9990" />
  </discovery-options>
    </remote>
</domain-controller>

<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:10.211.55.2}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
       <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:10.211.55.2}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecured">       
       <inet-address value="10.211.55.2" />    
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

I have followed this tutorial: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Clustering+and+Domain+Setup+Walkthrough

Following picture is the output on Fedora when starting domain.sh, and output on windows when starting domain.bat
[image: Left-domain.bat on Windows, Right-domain.sh on Fedora]

Comment: 9990 port is for `http-remoting` not `remoting` (port 9999). See http://docs.wildfly.org/14/High_Availability_Guide.html#Clustering_and_Domain_Setup_Walkthrough

Comment: This was exactly my issue. I just dont get why they don't fix their tutorial. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9990 port is for `http-remoting` not `remote` protocol (port 9999), change it and try again.

See: [Domain Configuration](http://docs.wildfly.org/14/High_Availability_Guide.html#domain-configuration)